# Get ESP32 Chip ID into a string variable (Arduino/C++ newbie here)

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

It's just a few days since I started using Arduino IDE ( programming an ESP32 ). As I learn, I am trying to write some snippets. I wanted to store the Chip ID of ESP32 into a variable (preferably string?) so that I can generate an unique device name. I looked through the ESP32 example programs and came across this program which just prints the Chip ID to the serial console.

```
  uint64_t chipid;

  chipid = ESP.getEfuseMac(); //The chip ID is essentially its MAC address(length: 6 bytes).
  Serial.printf("ESP32 Chip ID = %04X", (uint16_t)(chipid >> 32)); //print High 2 bytes
  Serial.printf("%08X\n", (uint32_t)chipid); //print Low 4bytes.
```

Now this works fine but I needed to store it into a variable in the following format "ESP32-0A1B3C4D5E6F" ( the last part of which is the Chip/MAC ID which is 6 bytes ). I went about some reading and currently reading and managed to get this far

```
  char ssid1[15];
  char ssid2[15];

  uint64_t chipid = ESP.getEfuseMac(); // The chip ID is essentially its MAC address(length: 6 bytes).
  uint16_t chip = (uint16_t)(chipid >> 32);

  snprintf(ssid1, 15, "%04X", chip);
  snprintf(ssid2, 15, "%08X", (uint32_t)chipid);

  Serial.print(ssid1);
  Serial.println(ssid2);
```

I am trying to read [this](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) which seems to be an [excellent article](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/) on handling Arduino strings but just being a few days old with Arduino/c++ I am having some difficulty in wrapping my head around some of the concepts. I come from a Python, PHP, Javascript background so I guess this is gona take a little bit of a time. I am getting the output that I want in the serial console but now I would need this in this format (MCUDEVICE-0A1B3C4D5E6F). I am sure this code can be written in a much nicer, cleaner manner but for now I need this to proceed with another snippet (which relies on device name in the above mentioned format). Can anyone provide some pointers while I try check out the different ways I could achieve this? I just want to be sure that I am not writing ugly (and dangerous code - crashes, buffer overruns etc). Greatly appreciate any pointers. I guess I am starting to get a little paranoid about handling strings ( especially on low memory devices like typical mcus ).

Comment: What is the purpose of the following line: uint16_t chip = (uint16_t)(chipid >> 32); ? Thanks

Comment: @ItamarVieira this copies the highest 16 bits from “chipid” (which is a 48-bit value in a 64-bit variable) to the “chip” variable (which is a 16-bit variable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine all your work into one single line with the snprintf. You aren't limited to just one variable, and you can add plain text:

```
char ssid[23];

snprintf(ssid, 23, "MCUDEVICE-%04X%08X", chip, (uint32_t)chipid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use:

```
char ssid[23];
snprintf(ssid, 23, "MCUDEVICE-%llX", ESP.getEfuseMac());
```

This way no need to bit-shift and extra middle variables...

Just watch out for capital X for uppercase result and small 'l' for type indication. (meaning use either llX or llx and not LLX).

Answer (score 0):

This works on an ESP32-S3 WROOM  on Arduino 1.8.19:

```cpp
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  String MCUtype = "ESP32s3" ;
  char ssid[14];
  snprintf(ssid, 14, "%llX", ESP.getEfuseMac());
  Serial.println(ssid); // 
  String ssid1 = ssid ; // convert from char to String
  Serial.println(ssid1);
  int StrLen = ssid1.length();
  Serial.printf("Length of the string %i characters \r\n",StrLen);
  String MAC ="";
  int i = 0; while ( i < 6) {  
    MAC = MAC + ssid1.substring(StrLen-2-2*i,StrLen-2*i)+":";
    i++ ;
  }
  MAC = MAC.substring(0,17); // remove last : 
  Serial.println(MAC);
  String Serialnumber = MCUtype+"-" ;
    int j = 3; while ( j < 6) {  
  Serialnumber = Serialnumber + ssid1.substring(StrLen-2-2*j,StrLen-2*j);
  j++ ;
  }
  Serial.println(Serialnumber);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```